# DriveApp.getFolders() Exception: Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I want to revoke the access to folders and files from google drive based on email from spreadsheet. But something goes wrong when getting the folders/files.

Error:

> Exception: You do not have permission to call DriveApp.getFolders.
>   Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive

I tried adding scopes:

```
scopesFile = {

    "oauthScopes": [
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"
    ]

}
```

But even that didn't help... Is there to force script to reauthorize?

```
function revokeGoogleDriveAccess(email, ui){
    const folders = DriveApp.getFolders();
    const files = DriveApp.getFiles();

    while(folders.hasNext()){
        var folder = folders.next();

        folder.revokePermissions(email);
    }

    while(files.hasNext()){
        var file = files.next();

        file.revokePermissions(email);
    }
}


function onEdits(e) {
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

    var email = ss.getRange("J" + rowLineNumber).getValue();

    revokeGoogleDriveAccess(email, ui); // <-- Google Drive Permissions Are Revoked Here. 
}
```

I expect it to revoke the access but instead I get stopped at `DriveApp.getFolders() / DriveApp.getFiles()`

Comment: Search "Third party" [here](https://myaccount.google.com) and remove all authorizations for your script.

Comment: i removed the authorizations, the problem is that when using on edit, it doesn't ask me for permissions. When i go to the script itself and run a function then it indeed asks me to give allowance. But then in spreadsheet the problem with scope still happens

Comment: Use Installed onEdit trigger

Comment: Are you in a Gsuite domain that has disallowed Drive scripts? Check your domain rules with your administrator. Also, yes, you must use an installed trigger. Read about the permissions level of simple triggers (hint: it's basically 0)

Comment: I'm sorry but could you show an example how to properly set the installed trigger up? I think im doing something wrong

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable should basically walk you through it. Documentation should always be consulted.

Comment: Using Installed onEdit solved the issue for me thanks a lot :)